# Migrating from USB 3.0 Micro B to Type B connector

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, soldering, high-speed

The current design uses a Micro B connector for the USB 3.0 connectivity. Unfortunately, this connector is susceptible to mechanical stress if the PCB is not handle with care, which results in ripped pads rendering the board unusable. I decided to replace it in the next revision with a Type B connector, which is THT, thus providing greater mechanical support.

The PCB is a 4-layer, in which all of the high-speed signals are located on the top layer. I have never used a THT component or VIAs for high-speed signals before. Is there anything I should consider or I just proceed with it? Also, we tend to hand solder the PCBs since it's a low production volume, with solder paste and hot air for SMT and iron for THT components on the board. Do you solder the USB 3.0 connector with the soldering iron as any other THT component, or is there anything special about handling a high-speed THT connector? Thank you.

Edit:

Although I will probably go with the solution proposed by Maple below, I am still interested to know the answer to my questions regarding Type B connector.

Answer (score 1):

> I decided to replace it in the next revision with a Type B connector,
> which is THT, thus providing greater mechanical support.

This is quite weird decision. There are plenty of Micro B sockets with THT prongs on the shield, like [this one](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/amphenol-icc-commercial-products/GSB343K33HR/2425947), for example. It still has SMT signal lines, so there is no need to redesign board much, just add two or four mounting holes. Your assembly process will not change much either, you simply add 15 seconds with soldering iron to it.

The only problem with this is the use of pretty much dead standard, but that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will consider that, too. The connectors I have used so far, like the 692622030100 from Wurth, did not have a THT part, so I assumed it's common for Micro B. What do you mean dead standard btw?

Comment: Just that there are almost no devices with USB 3.0 and the new devices either use USB-C or stay with USB 2.0. So the hosts with 3.0 are mostly used in 2.0 compatibility mode anyway. Trying to support 3.0 is wasted developer's time, IMHO.

Comment: @Maple I'm assuming you specifically mean SuperSpeed-B and SuperSpeed-Micro-B connectors when you say "3.0" is dead? Worth being clear, as the interplay between connector standards and digital standards is too complex for most mortals. But if that's what you mean, then I entirely agree.

Comment: (SuperSpeed-A is not quite as dead as the others, there will be A-to-C cables floating around for quite some time)

Comment: @hobbs yes, I mean those monstrosities. That's what Wurth [692622030100](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/w-rth-elektronik/692622030100/2627304) mentioned by OP is.